# Java Swing layout for a scrollable table?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable, jscrollpane

I currently have a JPanel inside of a JPanel where I would like to place my JScrollPane/JTable.  I am having trouble getting it placed where I want it. I would like to have the table fit the full width of the JPanel but only fill as much room as it needs to display all the dynamic data in the table vertically.

This is the code I currently have and the picture is what it looks like. The blue area is the nested panel for the table/scroll situation.  Also why is there a stupid gray box under the table.  How do I get rid of that?  Sorry about the pic, the data is sensitive.  Thanks.

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(50, 100, 300, 450);
    panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    contentPane.add(panel); //contentPane is the outter panel

    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table); //table was created earlier
    panel.add(scrollpane,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

[image: table panel]

Example program (I don't want that big rectangle under the table)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(350,100,1000,800);
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    JTable table = new JTable(5,5);
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    contentPane.add(scrollpane,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.revalidate();
}

}
```

Comment: I see setBounds, which makes me think you're using a null layout...

Comment: I'm using absolute positioning for the outter panel.  I don't see why that would make a difference.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, his code also isn't telling us the layout of `JPanel` instance `panel` but he is adding component with `BorderLayout` constraint :)

Answer (score 2):

> but only fill as much room as it needs to display all the dynamic data in the table vertically.

What if you have 100 rows, they won't all be able to display on the frame at one time?

Override the `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` method of JTable to return a reasonable number, this number should include the height of the JTableHeader. So you would probably want to cap the height at a reasonable number of rows + the table header.

```
panel.add(scrollpane,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

The NORTH constraint doesn't do anything. A JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default. You would need to set the layout of the panel to a BorderLayout.

Edit:

You have been asked to show your SSCCE that incorporates the suggestion made in these answers. You have not:

1. implemented the getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() method
2. done a pack() on the frame after you added all the components to the frame.

Other general comments.

1. Don't specify a size for the frame. That is what the pack() method is for. Even is you did you wouldn't hardcode a size. My monitor isn't even big enough to display a frame the size you specified.
2. Don't make a frame visible until you have added all the components to the frame.
3. The GUI should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: If there is 100 rows then it should fill the entire space vertically with the scroll (hense the point of the scrollpane).

Comment: That is not the way layout managers work. A component suggests hints for the layout manager to use. So the panel can't say I need 500 pixels of height because there might be another panel in the frame that also needs 500 pixels in height which would be too much for the frame. So each component should have a "preferred size". Then you pack the frame and use layout managers that allow the component to grow/shrink and the frame size changes, which means you should NOT be adding your component to the NORTH because if will never change height, even if more space is available.

Comment: So what layout do you recommend for managing this?  I'm just not sure how you get it to change size within a panel.

Comment: You were given an answer to that a week ago in one of your other questions. Not only did you not follow that advice you still haven't posted a `SSCCE`!!!

Comment: I added a short program.  As it runs, I'd like that big rectangle under the table not to be there.  I want the table to only show the cells.  And in this example I am setting the number of columns and rows, but in my actual program the rows, in particular, change depending on criteria, so it should be able to resize dynamically.

Comment: I still don't know why I would set a preferred size for it though.  There should never be a set size for the table.  It just shouldn't exceed the panel's area.  I don't understand why capping the size of the table would do anything.  I do not want a set size for the table.  Also the method pack() was not mentioned once in this thread, so while I appreciate the suggestion, don't act like I was ignorant of it.  Please read my question and provide useful input instead of complaining about me not doing things that are not relevant to what I want.

Comment: @Robert `Also the method pack() was not mentioned once in this thread` - seriously. You really should read before you comment. `Please read my question` - I have now it is your turn to read my answer.

Comment: @Robert `Also the method pack() was not mentioned once in this thread - seriously`. You really should read before you comment. `Please read my question` - I have now it is your turn to read my answer. I have made an honest effort to understand your requirement and have made what I think are appropriate suggestions. It is up to you to make an effort to implement my suggestion because the code you posted doesn't show any effort so I'm not sure how to help any more.

Answer (score 2):

> Also why is there a *stupid gray box* under the table. How do I get rid
>   of that?

Try using [**`table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setFillsViewportHeight%28boolean%29) after adding it to `JSCrollPane`: as you are doing now:

```
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   // other code
   panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // not sure whither you are already doing this

   JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
   table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

   panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

invoking `setFillsViewportHeight(true)` function set the `fillsViewportHeight` property. When this property is `true` the `table` uses the entire height of the container, even if the `table` doesn't have enough rows to use the whole vertical space.

**Note:**

1. I don't see you added a layout to the `panel` to which you have added the `JScrollPane`. I hope you know that `JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` as it's default layout which obeys component's preferred size hint. Again, `panel.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.NORTH);` produces ambiguity. As we use constraint: `BorderLayout.NORTH` to the component which has `BorderLayout` as it's layout manager.
2. Frame's content pane has `BorderLayout` as it's default layout manager You are setting bound to `panel` using `setBounds()` which we usually do while working with `AbsoluteLayout(null)` layout. And `AbsoluteLayout` is no go while *developing application in Swing*

Comment: JPanel is still using FlowLayout, which means the scroll pane may not fill the entire area...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I have noted the issue. It is really ambiguous: when he is doing, `panel.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.NORTH);`

Comment: I wouldn't want the table to fill the entire container though.  I just want it to be as large as it needs to be to view all the data and if it is larger than the container it should fill the entire thing with the scroll bar.

Comment: @Robert, `Get some people skills and grow up` - I think you are the one that needs the people skills. You are the one asking for help and then making comments when people try to help. It is incredibly hard to give you exact advice because of such a poor question. The code you posted is mostly useless.  Stating "it doesn't work" does not give us any information. Post your `SSCCE` the shows what you have tried based on all the suggestions you have received.

Comment: @camickr, the moderator has removed the comments as it seems. I flagged his comments. Lets hope he will post a `SSCCE` to let us know what he is trying to do exactly.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll try to make one.

Comment: I added a short program.  The method you had me call only changes the big rectangle under the table from gray to white.